# How can I model and simulate a resonant inductive square spiral coil in MATLAB?

Tags: passive-networks, inductance, matlab, wireless-charging

I was wondering if it was possible to model and simulate my WPT system in MATLAB to determine if my analytical calculations are correct. I want to model my system in MATLAB as I have seen on MathWorks you can do this for a circular spiral coil. Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

wireless power and Modeling Resonant Coupled was added to Matlab2017. I used it for wireless power transfer model, but you can change the geometry and model, frequency of simulation.

You can change this model:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/antenna/examples/modeling-resonant-coupled-wireless-power-transfer-system.html

**Edit**:
In function "createSpiral.m" change delta_phi "delta_phi=pi/2;"
The output like this:
[image]

For simulation, you should change 
createFeed(spiralobj,...,...); point
base on new feeder configuration

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I have given that a read and my problem is in changing the geometry to simulate a square spiral. I don't know how and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @williamfashanu, I updated the post for square spiral.